# Pandas: rolling windows with a sum product

Tags: python, pandas

There are a number of answers that each provide me with a portion of my desired result, but I am challenged putting them all together. My core Pandas data frame looks like this, where I am trying to estimate `volume_step_1`:

```
date        volume_step_0     volume_step_1
2018-01-01            100                 a
2018-01-02            101                 b
2018-01-03            105                 c
2018-01-04            123                 d
2018-01-05            121                 e
```

I then have a reference table with the conversion rates, for e.g.

```
step     conversion
0              0.60
1              0.81
2              0.18
3              0.99
4              0.75
```

I have another table containing point estimates of a Poisson distribution:

```
days_to_complete    step_no     pc_cases
0                         0         0.50
1                         0         0.40
2                         0         0.07
```

Using these data, I now want to estimate

```
volume_step_1 = 
(volume_step_0(today) * days_to_complete(step0, day0) * conversion(step0)) + 
(volume_step_0(yesterday) * days_to_complete(step0,day1) * conversion(step0))
```

and so forth.

How do I write some Python code to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling your dataframes (from top to bottom as `df1`, `df2`, and `df3`):

```
df1['volume_step_1'] = (
    (df1['volume_step_0']*
    df2.loc[(df2['days_to_complete'] == 0) & (df2['step_no'] == 0), 'pc_cases']* 
    df3.loc[df3['step'] == 0, 'conversion']) +
    df1['volume_step_0'].shift(1)*
    df2.loc[(df2['days_to_complete'] == 1) & (df2['step_no'] == 0), 'pc_cases']*
    df3.loc[df3['step'] == 0, 'conversion'])
```

### EDIT:

IIUC, you are trying to get a 'dot product' of sorts between the `volume_step_0` column and the product of the `pc_cases` and `conversion`for a particular `step_no`. You can `merge` df2 and df3 to match `steps`:

```
df_merged = df_merged = df2.merge(df3, how = 'left', left_on = 'step', right_on = 'step_no')
df_merged.head(3)

       step  conversion  days_to_complete  step_no  pc_cases
0   0.0         0.6               0.0      0.0      0.50
1   0.0         0.6               1.0      0.0      0.40
2   0.0         0.6               2.0      0.0      0.07
```

I'm guessing you're only using `stepk` to get `volume_step_k+1`, and you want to iterate the sum over the days. The following code generates a vector of `days_to_complete(step0, dayk)` and `conversion(step0)` for all values of `k` that are available in `days_to_complete`, and finds their product:

```
df_fin = df_merged[df_merged['step'] == 0][['conversion', 'pc_cases']].product(axis = 1)

0    0.300
1    0.240
2    0.042

   df_fin = df_fin[::-1].reset_index(drop = True)
```

Finally, you want to take the dot product of the `days_to_complete` * `conversion` vector by the `volume_step_0` vector, for a rolling window (as many values exist in `days_to_complete`):

```
vol_step_1 = pd.Series([df1['volume_step_0'][i:i+len(df3)].reset_index(drop = True).dot(df_fin) for i in range(0,len(df3))])
df1['volume_step_1'] = df1['volume_step_1'][::-1].reset_index(drop = True)
```

Output:

```
df1
         date volume_step_0  volume_step_1
0  2018-01-01           100            NaN
1  2018-01-02           101            NaN
2  2018-01-03           105         70.230
3  2018-01-04           123         66.342
4  2018-01-05           121         59.940
```

While this is by no means a comprehensive solution, the code is meant to provide the logic to "sum multiple products", as you had asked.

Comment: Thanks, in the context of my minimum viable dataset this works, but my actual timing lags go into hundreds of days and will vary significantly based on step. How would I be able to input an arbitrary number of days?

Comment: You mean if you want to estimate something like `volume_step_2`, `volume_step_3`, etc?

Comment: No, I can figure those out from your answer. Sticking with `volume_step_1`, my actual data has about 100+ days for each step in df2. How do I write the calculation without needing 100+ different sum statements?

Comment: FTFY, use `loc` if you're indexing on a boolean mask followed by a column selection... this reduces two `__getitem__` calls to one :)

Comment: Fantastic answer, by the way.